# Signal is disclosing peer-to-peer communication not sent through its own VPN to Google, or meta data thereof (i.e. call & duration, aliases & numbers)

Tags: jailbreak, vpn, privacy, caller-id, signal

**Premise**

Signal is disclosing peer-to-peer communication not sent through its own VPN to Google, or meta data thereof (i.e. call & duration, aliases & numbers) covertly, and without explicit disclosure of this fact in its ToS/EULA etc.. (Please see the attached screenshot below)<sup>[[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJlAH.jpg)</sup><sup>2</sup>

I have learned about this during research with a jailbroken iPhone running iOS 14.3, and AppFirewall<sup>[[3]](https://github.com/doug-leith/appFirewall)</sup><sup>[[4]](https://www.ios-repo-updates.com/repository/bigboss/package/ca.btraas.appfirewall)</sup>, a jailbreak tweak for iOS.

**Question**

Is there any other way to block this without having to jailbreak an iPhone, and having a non-OEM system-wide, app-to-app firewall system set up?

**Depction**

[image]

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>2</sup>: Transcript of image: [signal indicator at 1 out of 4 bars; "LTE", ¶, Contact name or number redacted in red ¶] "Signal Connecting... [¶] AppFirewall (1) [¶] Allow Signal to access [¶] 159.***.***.***.bc.googleusercontent.com? [¶] Warning: This task can't be resumed. You may need to restart this app if you click 'Allow'. [¶] Block[,¶] Allow[,¶ or] More Settings"

<sup>3</sup>: https://github.com/doug-leith/appFirewall

<sup>4</sup>: https://www.ios-repo-updates.com/repository/bigboss/package/ca.btraas.appfirewall

Comment: Have you [contacted Signal directly](https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/requests/new)? What did they recommend? As this is unexpected behaviour, be sure to [log a bug](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-iOS/issues/new/choose) with the developers.

Comment: I logged a bug report; still doubt its a bug.

Comment: If Signal is found to be working with the users of Pegasus, it would destroy their organisation. [Contact Signal](https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/requests/new) and ask for their help. You can then repeat your tests to see if their suggestions really help. See https://www.reddit.com/r/signal/comments/r3gmxc/signal_against_pegasus/ and https://signal.org/blog/cellebrite-vulnerabilities/ Good luck!

Comment: For reference, the bug report is https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-iOS/issues/5596

Comment: @GrahamMiln I don't think Signal, as a company, is in cahoots with Pegasus-user states; I still lean rather on it having to log some meta data for compliance, and it so happens to do that with a Google service, something like what they said on the crypto.SE site. Thanks for gathering all these links!

Comment: Messaged them directly with the link to the bug report.